# How do you Specify a Method to be a Destructor Rather than a Constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor

How do you specify a method to be a destructor rather than a constructor in C++? This confuses me very much. I can't tell the difference between the two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
MyClass::MyClass()   // Constructor 
MyClass::~MyClass()  // Destructor
```

Note the "~" in front of the destructor.

Comment: ~ is the not operator (logical), funny C++ designers

Comment: Nitpick: ~ is the *bitwise* not operator, not the *logical* not operator.

Answer (score 5):

If you are planning on deriving from that class, you will need to add virtual in your .h file like so:

```
class MyClass
{
  MyClass();   // Constructor 
  virtual ~MyClass();  // Destructor
};
```

this will ensure the destructor for both the base class and the derived class is called when the derived class is destroyed.

Comment: Only necessary if an instance of the derived class is deleted through a pointer to the base class.